# How to split a string in half, into two variables, in one statement?

Tags: ruby, string

I want to split `str` in half and assign each half to `first` and `second`

Like this pseudo code example:

```
first,second = str.split( middle )
```

Comment: Is there a problem with it?, what is the input and output, any "special" case to cover?

Comment: @SebastianPalma I just want to slice a string in half (two strings) and save both string in one elegant statement.

Comment: Have you tried something? Doesn't something like `first, second = 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet'.split(/Dolor/)` work?

Comment: I want a dynamic solution for any string example "123124" => "123" ,"124 or "999999" => "999" , "999"

Comment: Why don't you divide them on the string length?

Comment: I have done that but that is two lines for each half, I have to repeat "str.length" 3 times. I think it would be useful for a programming language to be able to easily refer to "the middle" or halves of data such as strings and would like to know if Ruby has something for this type of behavior.

Comment: What should a word with an odd number of characters return?

Comment: How do you handle unicode or multi-byte characters?  Do they count as 1 or 2+?

Comment: What you want is impossible for the very simple reason that Ruby doesn't have statements, only expressions.

Answer (score 6):

```
class String
  def halves
    chars.each_slice(size / 2).map(&:join)
  end
end
```

Will work, but you will need to adjust to how you want to handle odd-sized strings.

Or in-line:
`first, second = str.chars.each_slice(str.length / 2).map(&:join)`

Comment: have not heard of each_slice yet , thanks. What does join do?

Comment: join basically takes an array, and "joins" each element together into a single string.

Comment: You can use `chars` instead of `split('')` here.

Comment: @SagarPandya Yes, you are correct, will edit my answer. I knew there was a cleaner way to do that, couldn't think of it, thanks, lol.

Comment: @Cary Ah yes of course. I don't know if anyone has posted it but `char` vs `each_char` would be a good question/discussion on SO.

Comment: @SagarPandya `each_char` would be better than `chars` since `chars` will create a temporary `Array` where as `each_char` is just an `Enumerator`

Answer (score 4):

```
first,second = str.partition(/.{#{str.size/2}}/)[1,2]
```

---

### Explanation

You can use [partition](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-partition). Using a regex pattern to look for X amount of characters (in this case `str.size / 2`).

Partition returns three elements; head, match, and tail.  Because we are matching on any character, the *head* will always be a blank string.  So we only care about the *match* and *tail* hence `[1,2]`

Comment: I'm not seeing how `to_i` makes any difference.

Comment: @SagarPandya you're right, I was thinking it would return a float, but that's because I was dumb ;)  This is ruby, I think it would only return a float if it was `2.0` — I've now also changed `length` to `size` — thanks

Comment: I'd prefer `_, first, second = str.partition(...)` personally...don't like that `[1, 2]` at the end, but that's just a matter of style.

Comment: @SimpleLime yes that’s an option and a good one. Some people also prefer `second,first=s.partition(...).reverse`; whatever your flavor, *partition* was the highlight here ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here are two ways to do that

```
rgx = /
      (?<=                # begin a positive lookbehind
        \A                # match the beginning of the string
        .{#{str.size/2}}  # match any character #{str.size/2} times
      )                   # end positive lookbehind
      /x                  # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

```
def halves(str)
  str.split(rgx)
end
```

```
first, second = halves('abcdef')
  #=> ["abc", "def"]
first, second = halves('abcde')
  #=> ["ab", "cde"]
```

The regular expression is conventionally written

```
/(?<=\A.{#{str.size/2}})/
```

Note that the regular expression matches a location between two successive characters.

---

```
def halves(str)
  [str[0, str.size/2], str[str.size/2..-1]]
end
```

```
first, second = halves('abcdef')
  #=> ["abc", "def"]
first, second = halves('abcde')
  #=> ["ab", "cde"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Note: This only works with even length strings.

Along the line of your pseudocode,

```
first, second = string[0...string.length/2], string[string.length/2...string.length]
```

If `string` is the original string.